# How to take multiple input using nextLine in java

Tags: java

I am getting error while running the below code "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0"
And I want to know the difference between next() and nextLine() method.

```
        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int q=sc.nextInt();
        String str[] = new String[q];
        for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
        {
            str[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        sc.next();
        for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
            System.out.println(str[i]);
            if(str[i].charAt(0) == 'I' ){
               String s1[] = str[i].split("\\s+");`enter code here`
               System.out.println(s1[0]);`enter code here`
            int value = Integer.valueOf(s1[1]);
            arr[value]+= 1;
            }
            if(str[i].charAt(0) == 'U'){
                String aa ="aman 2";
                String s2[]= aa.split("\\s+");
                int pos = Integer.valueOf(s2[1]);  
                int val = Integer.valueOf(s2[2]);
                arr[pos] = val;
            }
            if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("left"))
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    int tmp = arr[0];
                    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
                        arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                    }
                    arr[j]=tmp;
                }
            if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
                  int k = 0;
                    int temp = arr[0];
                    for(k=0;k<n-1;k++){
                        arr[k]=arr[k+1];
                    }
                    arr[k]=temp;
            }
            if(str[i].equals('?')){
                String s4[] = str[i].split("\\s+");
                int position = Integer.valueOf(s4[1]);
                System.out.println(arr[position]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the line where the exception occured?

Comment: in which line the error is?

Comment: By the way, a string cannot equal a char...

Comment: also consider [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/85421)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the following line:

```
if(str[i].charAt(0) == 'I' ){
```

If `str` is an empty String, you cannot get the first character. You can test ifa String is empty by using `.isEmpty()`.

`Scanner#nextLine()` reads (as the name says) the next line from an `InputStream`(in your case `System.in`).

`Scanner#next()` **can** read the next line butit can also **read less**. It reads until it reaches certain delimitors.

You can configure the delimitors. By default, it splits by delimitors like spaces, line breaks etc.